# proper usage of clauses

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the following sentence what is the meaning of **judges**, is it correctly used?

> The decision comes on the heels of another ordering **judges** to end the practice of flogging, replacing it with jail time, fines or community service and bringing one of the kingdom’s most controversial forms of public punishment to a close.

[To Read Full Article](https://www.thehindu.com/news/international/saudi-arabia-ends-death-penalty-for-minors/article31440972.ece?homepage=true)

Comment: The judges were ordered to cease the practice of flogging. In this sentence, "judges" is used as a noun meaning judicial officials.

Comment: You may find it easier to understand this sentence if you insert a comma between `another` and `ordering`, or other mentally split / pause there.